# Mysql how to join tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have three tables:

- Table 1 contains a primary key.
- Table 2 contains a foreign key that is equal to primary key of table 1.
- Table 3 contains a foreign key that is equal to primary key of table 2.

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to SELECT information from table 2 and 3 while only knowing the primary key of table 1? If so please give a brief example of the SELECT QUERY. I have tried doing an Inner join but got a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, it's simple. An inner join should do it. Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @codenoob let me know if my answer worked for you.

Comment: @Barmar and whatsup Barmar :), I ended up not going with pheanstalk after all. I asked the developers of beanstalk a few questions and eventually decided to use a database for the inter server script communication. Hopefully it gets the job done, though I guess I'll find out in a week or so

Comment: If you get a syntax error how bout posting the query and the error

Comment: I think it would be ok to remove the PHP tag from this, wouldn't it?

Comment: thanks I had a comma in front of FROM, that was what causing the error the whole time, I thought it were possible to do that type of join.... Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

**Example:**

```
table_a              table_b             table_c
 _______________      _______________     _______________
|  id  |  name  |    |  id  | gender |   |  id  |   age  |
|------+--------|    |------+--------|   |------+--------|
|   1  |  sam   |    |   1  |    m   |   |   1  |   18   |
|------+--------|    |------+--------|   |------+--------|
|   2  |  ana   |    |   2  |    f   |   |   2  |   22   |
|------+--------|    |------+--------|   |------+--------|
```

In order to get the following result:

```
 _________________________________ 
|  id  |  name  | gender |   age  |
|------+--------+--------+--------|
|   1  |  sam   |    m   |   18   |
|------+--------+--------+--------|
|   2  |  ana   |    f   |   22   |
```

You could use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.gender, c.age
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN table_c AS c
    ON a.id = c.id
```

**P.S.:** only answered this to do the ascii art xD!

Comment: I don't care how you write code at home, but please use ANSI JOIN when posting answers here. We try to promote good coding style.

Comment: @Barmar would the newly edited sql statement now be equivalent to the previous one? Except now I'm using left join instead of the default inner, which I prefer just to not loose any rows

Comment: Yes, that's much better.