# Find number of items left based upon credit's id and all ids prior

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `t` variable which contains 100 and one table .

that table name `credit` and it contains the following data

```
Id
1
2
3
```

I would like the result set to look like this:

```
result
99 (100 - 1)
97 (100 - 2 - 1)
94 (100 - 3 - 2 - 1)
```

So far, I have been able to use the following code successfully:

```
set @t=100;
 select @t:=@t-id as result from credit;
```

Is there a way to do this without using a variable?

Comment: show what is in credit (id). Show the table, and the expected results

Comment: Look at the tables in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37472510) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37940132). Do a better job of explaining

Comment: if i have 10 pens. i sold this pen to three people
first people buy 1 pens
second people buy 2 pens
third people buy 3 pens

i have result set of selling number of pens
that credit table id column 

and i want to result set how many pens are not sell per people

Comment: You want 99,97,94. Your query got that. What is the question? That you want an approach that does NOT use variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple and you shouldn't have to use the variable at all:

```
SELECT 100-(SELECT SUM(c2.id) FROM credit c2 WHERE c2.id <= c.id)
FROM credit c;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fc3c6/6

The subquery simply gets the sum of all numbers including, and prior to the credit id.

Comment: that gets 99,98,97,96 ... not what he wants apparently

Comment: I don't even know what his question is. His works fine apparently, and looking for a different approach?

Comment: this result set decrements each value from 100
but i want decrement like following

100-1=99
99-2=97
 97-3=94 as like

Comment: Understood. Working on a solution now.

Comment: @ManojMuduli Found a solution for you.

Comment: nice job Pachonk +1

Comment: can it possible using local variable? @Pachonk